# Is multicollinearity acceptable where one variable is the anomaly between, or sum of, other variables?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, covariance, variance-inflation-factor

I'm using the variance inflation factor (VIF) to calculate multi-collinearity between the variables I'd like to include within a regression model. I was reading this article: https://statisticalhorizons.com/multicollinearity, which mentions that high VIFs caused by the inclusion of powers or products of other variables can be acceptable. I was wondering if this exception also applies to the anomaly between, or sum of variables? For example would it be acceptable for me to include variable A, and variable B-A, if the VIF>5 when including both?

Comment: Multicollinearity is acceptable even when one variable is not the anomaly between, or sum of, other variable. There might be reasons not to want multicollinearity, but it isn't inherently a deal-breaker.

Comment: @Dave, thanks - that's what I was thinking/hoping, and including both in the final model improves the R2 statistic, but I was worried that explaining the contribution of each parameter using the linear regression coefficients might not be so valid if there was a VIF greater than 5 between them.

Comment: In-sample or out-of-sample $R^2$ statistic? Inclusion of additional variables (usually) improves in-sample $R^2$ values but need not generalize to have good out-of-sample performance.

Comment: @Dave I spllit my data into 80% train and 20% test, and the statistics are very similar between them (train: R2=0.767, rRMSE=15.9%, MAE=8.8% and test: R2=0.763, rRMSE=16.3% and MAE=9.3%).